# How to properly create GraphX with attributes for Nodes and Edges

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm running on Jupyter Notebook, using *spylon kernel*, a scala program that performs some actions on a network.

After some preprocessing I end up having two DataFrames, one for nodes and one for edges, of the following kind:

For *Nodes*

```
+---+--------------------+-------+--------+-----+
| id|                node|trip_id| stop_id| time|
+---+--------------------+-------+--------+-----+
|  0|0b29d98313189b650...| 209518|u0007405|56220|
|  1|45adb49a23257198e...| 209518|u0007409|56340|
|  2|fe5f4e2dc48b97f71...| 209518|u0007406|56460|
|  3|7b32330b6fe10b073...| 209518|u0007407|56580|
+---+--------------------+-------+--------+-----+
only showing top 4 rows

vertices_complete: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, node: string ... 3 more fields]
```

For *edges*

```
+------+-----+----+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
|   src|  dst|time|method|weight|walk_time|wait_time|bus_time|
+------+-----+----+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
| 65465|52067|2640|  walk|2640.0|     1112|     1528|       0|
| 68744|52067|1740|  walk|1740.0|      981|      759|       0|
| 55916|52067|2700|  walk|2700.0|     1061|     1639|       0|
|124559|52067|1440|  walk|1440.0|     1061|      379|       0|
| 23036|52067|1800|  walk|1800.0|     1112|      688|       0|
+------+-----+----+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows

edges_DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [src: bigint, dst: bigint ... 6 more fields]
```

I want to create a Graph object out of this, to do PageRank, find shortest paths, etc. Therefore I convert these objects to RDD:

```
val verticesRDD : RDD[(VertexId, (String, Long, String, Long))] =  vertices_complete.rdd
    .map(row =>
        (row.getAs[Long](0), 
         (row.getAs[String]("node"), row.getAs[Long]("trip_id"), row.getAs[String]("stop_id"), row.getAs[Long]("time"))))

val edgesRDD : RDD[Edge[Long]] = edges_DF.rdd
    .map(row => 
         Edge( 
         row.getAs[Long]("src"), row.getAs[Long]("dst"), row.getAs[Long]("weight")))

val my_graph = Graph(verticesRDD, edgesRDD)
```

Any operation, that can be even PageRank (tried also with the shortest path, and the error still persists)

```
val ranks = my_graph.pageRank(0.0001).vertices
```

raises the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 233.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 233.0 (TID 9390, DESKTOP-A7EPMQG.mshome.net, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2209)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1157)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1151)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.VertexRDDImpl.count(VertexRDDImpl.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.Pregel$.apply(Pregel.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.PageRank$.runUntilConvergenceWithOptions(PageRank.scala:431)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.PageRank$.runUntilConvergence(PageRank.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps.pageRank(GraphOps.scala:380)
  ... 40 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

I think there is something wrong with the initialization of the RDD objects (and also I would like to add attributes to edges [time, walk_time etc...], too, in addition to the weight), but I cannot figure out how to do it properly. Any help, please?

Comment: `stopid` is a string. You can't cast it to a long.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing it out. I have just edited the OP and rerun my code, but there is still the same error

Comment: `weight` is a float, you need to getAs[Float], not long.

Comment: How to properly modify the argument `RDD[Edge[Long]] `, in this case?
It expects a Long, given this syntax.

Comment: you can cast to long in the dataframe first, before converting to rdd

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
Could you please also write the syntax to add attributes to edges, when converting to rdd? I could not figure it out